# Cannot connect to smtp server that requires authentication

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am trying to connect to an smtp server that requires authentication.

This is the C# code i am using to send the email:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = _smtpServerHost;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Send(GetMessage());
```

The send function raised the error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. 
The server response was: Must authenticate before sending mail
```

Is there a step that I am missing to connect to the smtp server?

I tried to connect to a test server we have running but that didn't work. I also tried to connect to [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/). I can connect to it when I am not requiring authentication, but not when i am requiring auth.

Comment: Are you sure the credentials you are using are correct?

Comment: I'm using authentication and I don't use the line `smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` - have you tried removing that?

Comment: you can try to connect to the server directly telnet into port 25, and try to authenticate http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2003/exchange2003_SMTP_Auth_Login.htm . Alternatively, look at exception thrown, specifically inner exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out you need to set `UseDefaultCredentials = false` **before** you assign the `client.Credentials`. If you set it after it will not send the AUTH command.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft States that SmtpClient is not recommended. You should use MailKit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.0

**We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead. For more information, see SmtpClient shouldn't be used on GitHub.**

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685159/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)