# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: c#

I have a Problem, when i m sending a mail through this code then error is occured that "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. "

and my code is :

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add("info@msslindia.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("info@msslindia.com");
    string body = "<table><tr><td>Company Name:</td><td>" + txt_cname.Text + "</td></tr><tr><td>Address With No.:</td><td>" + txt_addwithno.Text + "</td></tr><tr><td>Contact Person:</td><td>" + txt_conperson.Text + "</td></tr><tr><td>Email Id</td><td>" + txt_email.Text + "</td></tr><tr><td>Description</td><td>" + txt_description.Text + "</td></tr></table>";
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@msslindia.com", "xyz");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);


    txt_cname.Focus();
    txt_cname.Text = "";
    txt_addwithno.Text = "";
    txt_conperson.Text = "";
    txt_email.Text = "";
    txt_description.Text = "";

}
```

Comment: Is this question solved? Because I'm having same problem and trying to fix it..

Comment: You may want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11513412/676508

Answer (score 15):

Google may prevent an application from accessing your account 
Here you can enable applications to access google account with your credentials:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 4):

I think you should set [UseDefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) to false, since you define credentials for the connection.

> Set this property to **true** when this SmtpClient object should, if
>   requested by the server, authenticate using the default credentials of
>   the currently logged on user.
>
> [...]
>
> If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to **false**, then *the value
>   set in the Credentials property will be used* for the credentials when
>   connecting to the server

Answer (score 2):

Try the port 587(it worked for me ) 
and also set UseDefaultCredentials to false.
Set this and try to send the mail

Comment: ok try after removing the line UseDefaultCredentials or commenitng it for the time being

Comment: can u send me your code snippet so that i can take a look into it

Comment: Hey,i tried the code you pasted here,it is working absolutely fine.From which account you are trying to send the mail from?

Comment: actuall it is configured on outlook.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11567/discussion-between-vipin-and-sanat-pandey)

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using the wrong port.

you should use 465

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

cheers

Comment: Yes you are right, 25 is the generic smtp port. You may want to use 465 or 587

Answer (score 0):

The port doesn't really matter as System.Net.Mail does not support implicit SSL, in other words it totally ignores the "Port" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set this up through SQL Server 2012 Database Mail, and was getting the same message.

I was never able to get it to work using my primary g-mail account, which uses double authentication, even after using an Application-specific password. I ended up trying my secondary account, which does not have double auth, and it worked immediately. So for anyone who can't get it working using one of the solutions above, try it with a standard auth g-mail account.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft States that SmtpClient is not recommended. You should use MailKit it will work for sure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.0

**We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead. For more information, see SmtpClient shouldn't be used on GitHub.**